# Change navigation text in squarespace template?

Tags: css

I'm new to this and trying to learn but there's one thing I'm stuck on.
Basically I have pages in a dropdown menu and the text is black in the black box it's in.

I can change this by changing the background to white, but I don't want to change the background to white. I just want to individually change the dropdown menu text to white so it can be seen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y3EC.jpg

my website is simworksperformance.com
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What technology are you using to build your website ? Is it possible to provide some code examples of how you create the dropdown ?

Comment: i'm using squarespace. basically i just need custom code or whatever to make the dropdown text white. cause if i turn the main navigation text white it'll turn the dropdown text white, but people won't be able to see the text in the main nav if i do that. so i need white text for just the dropdown